# scala add element to option iterable

Tags: scala

I am learning Scala and encountered a very basic data type problem:

Below is the method:

```
def getStuffDone(stuffs: (stuff, Option[Iterable[stuff]])): stuff = {
    
    //Combine stuff with Option[Iterable[stuff]]
    
    //Then return the best stuff

}
```

And I tried with

```
val results = stuffs._2.get++Seq(stuffs._1)
```

But encountered runtime error because `stuffs._2` is of type `None` in some cases. Hence, `None.get` is wrong.

How should I combine this? After combining, the `results` should be `Iterable[stuff]` type?

Comment: Sorry I posted an answer without realizing you wanted result to be an `Iterable`, what should `result` be if there is a `None`? Empty Iterable? If you can clarify that, I can edit the answer accordingly

Comment: @sinanspd Thank you very much! If there's a ```None```, I want the ```result``` to be ```Iterable``` as well. Because the first element ```stuff``` will definitely be present. result will be a one element ```iterable``` in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `map` over the Option. See the documentation [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html#map%5BB%5D(f:A=%3EB):Option%5BB%5D)

`map` will only run the function it is given, if the `Option` is a `Some`

EDIT: changing default behaivior per comments

Here is an example of what your code will look like

```
val x : Tuple2[Int, Option[Iterable[Int]]] = (5, Some(List(1, 2)))
val x2 : Tuple2[Int, Option[Iterable[Int]]] = (5, None)

val results = x._2.map(_ ++ List(x._1)).getOrElse(List(x._1)) // result equals List(1, 2, 5)
val results2 = x2._2.map(_ ++ List(x._1)).getOrElse(List(x._1)) // results equals List()
```

Note that the `++` operator returns a **new** Iterable and **doesn't** modify the original. So in this case `x` will still equal `(5, Some(List(1, 2)))`

Also as a side note, I am not sure what you are trying to do but you probably don't need to use an Iterable here. A more specific type like `List` will do just fine. As a general good practice, keep your types as tight as possible

[Demo here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bQEYT4k5R8ytTi7e8jnmFQ)

Answer (score 2):

This appends `stuffs._1` to the end of the `Iterable[Stuff]` if it exists, otherwise it's a single element `Iterable`.

```
def getStuffDone(stuffs: (Stuff, Option[Iterable[Stuff]])): Iterable[Stuff] =
  stuffs._2.fold(Iterable(stuffs._1))(_ ++ Iterable(stuffs._1))
```

Your question and comments appear to contradict the posted code which returns a single `Stuff` that is supposed to be `//... the best stuff`.